# .NET Maui radio button text not visible in dark mode?

Tags: radio-button, maui, textcolor, ios-darkmode

Anyone else notice that the RadioButton Content (at least on iOS) ignores the TextColor attribute? In Dark mode it displays the content as white text no matter what I set it to.

```
<RadioButton Content="Black Content Text" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=Black}" />
```

Is this a known Maui bug?

Comment: You can use my RadioButton control, I anyway don't like some maui controls they don't have a lot of needed functionality https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls Hope this helps you out. Let me know if you want me to add this as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. The issue is that when setting `TextColor` attribute of `RadioButton` in **Mac** or **iOS**, it failed to change the `TextColor` as expected and not just in dark mode. In conclusion, this is a known issue that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6430